# Should I build boost 32 or 64?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

I am about to build the boost binaries and was wondering whether I should build them as 32 or 64 bit? I was unsure as I didn't know whether this was in relation to my computer's environment (win 7 64) or the type of application I will be producing. I am using MSVC 2010 Express and haven't changed the compiler it uses, so I suspect that the 32 bit compiler is active.

I have no interest in writing 64-bit only apps (I am happy with how MSVC is functioning now, I just want to add the boost libs), so which build should I perform?

(Win32) `b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage`

OR

(x64) `b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building 32-bit apps, you clearly need a 32-bit build of Boost to do it with.

I'm not sure I'd build a 32-bit version myself though -- it's a lot quicker and easier to [download](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) it from BoostPro.

Comment: that link is dead